Where in the Gospels does Jesus explain what 'The Truth' is?
We read in Jn 14:5-6( KJV):

Thomas saith unto him, Lord, we know not whither thou goest; and how can we know the way?Jesus saith unto him, I am the way, the truth, and the life: no man cometh unto the Father, but by me.

Elsewhere, Jesus explains what he means by calling himself 'The Way' and 'The Life'. He also has a long discourse  on his being the true witness of the Father( Jn 8) , and also tells Pilate that he came to witness The Truth(Jn 18:37). But he keeps silence against Pilate's question on Truth(Jn 18:38). My question is : Where in the Gospels does Jesus explain what The Truth is ?

To quote N. T. Wright: "When Jesus wanted fully to explain what his forthcoming death was all about, he didn’t give them a theory. He gave them a meal."

@phantom-99w  Welcome to the site which you've joined today. Looking forward to reading your answers, and any questions you might have.

The Apostle John details this in his Gospel. His prologue explains the miraculous nature of the One who "became flesh and dwelt among us" - this Word of God, who was with God in the beginning, and who was God, who became the man, Jesus Christ.
Then in verse 16 of chapter 1, we are told this about Jesus Christ:

"For the law was given by Moses, but grace and truth came by Jesus
Christ. No man hath seen God at any time; the only begotten Son, who
is in the bosom of the Father, he hath declared him." John 1:17-18
A.V.

This logically means that everything Jesus said about the Father is Truth. His declarations about God the Father are truthful declarations. This obviously includes everything else Jesus said on Earth; the One who is the Truth speaks truth at all times. He is Truth personified.
After telling Pilate that he came into the world to bear witness to the truth, and that everyone who is of the truth hears his voice, Pilate asked "What is truth?" (John 18:37-38).
That clearly showed that Pilate did not hear Jesus' voice. Oh, yes, he heard the few words Jesus spoke to him, face to face, but he did not see that Truth was standing before him - personified in the person of Christ who is the Truth.
Those words above were the last words Jesus spoke to Pilate. He remained silent when questioned further because Jesus knew that Pilate could not hear his voice - the voice of truth. He could only hear words.
And so it is and has been in all the centuries following. Millions upon millions have read the words of Jesus (as recorded in the Bible) and have even learned his parables and been amazed at his miracles and signs, but they have not heard his voice. They have only read words. Yet the Word of God is the Way, the Truth and the Life.
The answer to the question is simply this - every word of Jesus, recorded in all the gospel accounts, relates to the gospel truth we need to believe as Truth, in order to start following the Way, and to gain the Life. Until we accept that the Word of God is Truth personified in Jesus Christ (John 1:17), we will never find the only Way to the Father, or to enter into Life everlasting.

Thanks, Anne. Your answer is like a meditative prayer. I wish I could add  'Amen'  to it

+1 Very nice comment! It helped me much.

George F, I hope you wanted to thank Anne for her Comment on your own Answer. Would you mind its shifting ?

Good question.
In fact, this was one question I had pondered over for so long.
I was happy for Pilate that he came close to asking the same question to Jesus to the face point blank. Yet I was annoyed with him for not pressing that question enough to get the answer out from Jesus. So close yet such a silence.
But then being a political person, he was not that eager to know the truth. To them truth depended on convenience.
So, I was lost for quite some time.

“Pilate said to Him, What is truth?” (John 18:38).

But to my surprise, Jesus had answered this very same question a couple of hours before Pilate asked Him this.
It sounds like a definition!

“Your Word is Truth” (John 17:17)!

So, yes, the Word of God is the Truth.

“And now, O Lord Jehovah, You are God, and Your Words are truth”
(2 Sam 7:28).


“The Words of Jehovah are pure Words, like silver refined in an
earthen furnace, purified seven times. You shall keep them, O Jehovah;
You shall preserve them from this generation forever” (Psalms 12:6-7).

Where can we find the Word of God?

“And these were more noble than those in Thessalonica, for they
received the Word with all readiness, daily examining the
Scriptures if these things are so” (Acts 17:11).

So, we see the Word of God in the Scriptures.
Jesus also said:

“But Jesus answered and said unto them, Ye do err, not knowing
the scriptures, nor the power of God” (Mat 22:29).

Answer
"What is truth?” (John 18:38).
“Your Word is Truth” (John 17:17).

Here is the Etymology, By LSJ Lexicon (Henry Liddell, Robert Scott, Stuart Jones, Robert Mackenzie)
Ἀλήθεια (aléthea [noun]) < ἀληθής (alethés [adjective]): adjective, originally identifying things or events, meaning "one who cannot be hidden", "(who is) real" as opposed to the adjective “(who is) false”. After Homer, the adjective also defined persons, meaning "one who does not deceive, who does not lie", hence “φιλαλήθης” (philalíthes = friend of the truth or who loves the truth). From the adjective “ἀληθής” came the abstract noun “ἀλήθεια” (aléthea = relatived to the meaning of truth), which literally means "state in which nothing is hidden", therefore "real state" —in contrast to “ψεῦδος” (psévdhos = false, lie, hypocrisy, etc [everything that is not real state])— and in the case of persons it means "honesty". The word “ἀλήθεια” was widely used as a term in philosophy, where it usually denotes "a state of knowledge, recollection, memory" as opposed to “λήθη” (léthe = oblivion). Etymologically, the adjective “ἀληθής”, which replaced the word “ἐτεός” (eteós) {I think it has to do with the Greek word alethés, but I believe, according to the possible premologies (because they are not confirmed), that it is the opposite of "κενός" (kenós = empty, from "κενε[F]oς > κεν[F]oς > κενος", i.e., behind what someone claims or does, there is a substance, reality, truth, which pushes him to do what he does.}, is considered a compound with the preffix ἀ- (negative prefix) and the second compound the noun “λῆθος” (Doric λᾶθος) or “λήθη” (forgetfulness), not excluding the direct connection of the adjective with the verb “λήθω” {létho (parallel form of the verb is “λανθάνω” [lantháno])}.
My personal view
My personal view, regarding the concept generally used in the New Testament, has to do with the actual situation that a true Christian experiences. I.e., a Christian learns not to pretend (externalizing his true self), to have faith in the living God (real: alethés = in both senses, perhaps, of the word, i.e. he who speaks the truth, does not pretend, as also, he exists, is alive, and his works are seen in our eyes by which we understand what God represents), not to lie, not to make mistakes, but not to feel like he's being fair, not to be forgotten (rejected) by God (God's gaze, his attention and care, is upon his children; God recognizes you, which means that you live in truth; while others live in a lie, i.e. Away from God and his attribute, his designation, his name [the name is an attribute] which is the truth). So then, the noun "ἀλήθεια" (aléthea) has come, and has taken on another dimension from Christ. Because, no longer does “aléthea” represent a man who looks to please the desires of his flesh, which is a natural thing for a man, and I mean food pleasures, the importance a man wants to feel, wanting to believe in a god, which happens to be a foreign god, pleasure in general, and carnal intercourse with the opposite sex using abuse (God allows monogamy and, I think, that is what the scripture is telling us, within the context of marriage); all these things are natural for man to want, therefore, natural for him to do them, therefore, he who does them is in a truth. But, Christ came and changed that. He changed the truth. Truth now is to be in the will of God in the full meaning of the word "will".

Welcome to the site, George F.  Going into the Greek of the word 'alethea' was interesting. And your concluding three sentences were significant.

Jesus had already preemptively answered Pilate before he asked his famous question. “What is truth?”.

John 18:36 For this purpose I was born and for this purpose I have come into the world—to bear witness to the truth. Everyone who is of the truth listens to my voice.”


John 14 Jesus saith unto him, I am the way, the truth, and the life: no man cometh unto the Father, but by me.

If we listen to Jesus’ voice, we have the truth. It is not complicated or mysterious. All that Jesus spoke was from the Father, he bore witness to all that the Father had in mind for His creation and its salvation. Which is quite different to all the other ideas about life ( and the next life) pressed onto us by the temporary god of this age.

In the Gospel of John the idea of Truth is a constant theme. The word "truth" appears in this gospel 22 times compared two twice in Mark and once each in Matthew and Luke. Naturally there are many opinions as to how John (or Jesus) defines the term.
Clearly, however, Jesus is the embodiment of the Truth. So we might say that for John,  the Truth is Jesus and Jesus is the Truth. This, of course is a circular definition and not very satisfying. Jesus is also the Light, which symbolizes Truth. (John uses the word "light" 17 times). Generally, however, the idea of embodiment is crucial, both for light and for truth.
John 3:

20 For everyone who does wicked things hates the light and does not
come toward the light, so that his works might not be exposed. 21 But
whoever lives the truth comes to the light, so that his works may be
clearly seen as done in God.

This dovetails with other scriptures such as James 1:22 ("Be doers of the word and not hearers only") and Matthew 7:21 (“Not everyone who says to me, ‘Lord, Lord,’ will enter the kingdom of heaven, but only the one who does the will of my Father in heaven.")
Jesus gives a synopsis of the Truth that leads to eternal life several times in the synoptic gospels: love God with all one's heart and love one's neighbor as oneself. (Luke 10:27, Mark 12:30-31, Matthew 22:38-39)
Conclusion: For John and also other texts, the Truth is the embodiment of Jesus' words. The Golden Rule is a synopsis of the Truth, but in another sense, Truth needs not be defined so much as it must be realized in deeds. Jesus is the supreme example of that principle.

I remember doing a bible study and having a worship service on John 8. This is the verse that stands out to me regarding "the Truth":

31 To the Jews who had believed him, Jesus said, “If you hold to my teaching, you are really my disciples.32Then you will know the truth, and the truth will set you free.”

The Truth is found when we hold to Jesus' teaching. I suppose it is of an inner enlightenment that is found deep within once you truly grasp and understand and put into practice the teachings of Christ. Jesus mentions you will know the truth, and the truth will set you free. Having that firm understanding of Jesus' teachings and living them out day after day after day builds up the Truth in you - and what more - Jesus Christ wants the truth to live inside of us. We are his people, of course we need it more than anything or anyone else. The purpose of the Truth is that it sets you free - from every bondage, and every chain. That is the power, of the Truth.

Welcome to the site, Alex. John 8:32 is a very good text that does give an answer to the question.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
